# Удаление пробелов при копипасте в textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

WindowsForm, в textbox вставляется число с пробелом (25 799). Далее идет:

```
Convert.ToInt32(textbox.text);
```

или

```
Int32.Parse(textbox.text);
```

При каких-либо математических действиях приложение крашится.

Как избавится от пробелов? Нужно, чтобы они удалялись после “вставить” в textbox или удалялись при конвертации типов.
Хотел заменить, на numericUpDown с ним тоже беда, после вставки числа с пробелом сбрасывает в 0.

Comment: удалите пробелыс помощью  Replace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Convert.ToInt32(textbox.Text.Replace(" ", "").Trim());
```

Comment: Спасибо! Работает.